# Confused about why I'm getting a maximum recursion depth exceeded error in django __unicode__(self) method

Tags: python, django

I have a Crop model:

```
class Crop(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species, null=True)
    def pref_common_name(self):
        pcn = self.commonname_set.filter(preferred=True)
        if pcn[0]:
            return pcn[0]
        else:
            return "No Preferred Common Name"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.pref_common_name, self.species)
```

which has many common names:

```
class CommonName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    preferred = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    crop = models.ForeignKey(Crop, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.preferred:
            try:
                temp = CommonName.objects.get(preferred=True, crop=self.crop)
                if self != temp:
                    temp.preferred = False
                    temp.save()
            except CommonName.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        super(CommonName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

when the `__unicode__` method is called, I get the recursion error.  But I cant see why this should be the case.  Can someone explain to my why?  I should be able to get a string from a related object to return in the unicode method, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please fix the `pcn commonname_set.filter(preferred=True)` line? What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, yes, meant to be a variable declaration.  Fixed.

Comment: how does species look? Also edit the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: `return "%s (%s)" % (self.pref_common_name, self.species)`  should probably be: `return "%s (%s)" % (self.pref_common_name(), self.species)` and `if pcn[0]:` should be `if pcn.exists():` because `pcn[0] will throw an IndexError if that query returns no results.

Comment: Please include the stack trace… (or at least the beginning of it)

Answer (score 2):

In the save method of your `CommonName` you call `temp.save()` which leads to the error.